# Find $(f^{-1})'(3)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, inverse, inverse-function

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}\space \space \space f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc}x^2-2x,&x\leq0\\-x^2-2x,&x>0\end{array}\right.$. Find $(f^{-1})'(3)$.

My attempt:

First, it's easy to see that $f(x)$ is injective $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$ By doing the first derivative table we see that $Im_f=\mathbb{R}.$ so then $f$ is surjective and then $f$ is bijective and it has an *inverse* function.

$$f^{-1}(f(x))=x$$

differentiating both sides we get that $(f^{-1}(f(x)))'=\frac 1{f'(x)}$.

$f(x)=3\implies x = -1$ unique solution so then $\boxed{(f^{-1})'(3)=\frac 1{f'(x)}=-\frac 14}$

Second solution: (which i don't really understand what happens here)

I want to define $f^{-1}(x).$

First case ($x\leq0):$

$\implies f(x)=x^2-2x \space \space \space \forall x\leq0.$

$$f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x+1}+1 \space\space\space \forall x\geq -1.$$

so then: $f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{x+1}+1 \space \space \space \forall \space x\in[-1,0]?$ Also when do we use the $+$ sign and the $-$ for the square root?

Second case ($x>0$):

$\implies f(x)=-(x+1)^2+1\implies f^{-1}(x)=\pm\sqrt{1-x}-1 \space \space \space \forall x\in(0,1]?$ same question about the sign of the square root.

so then we get

$$\boxed{f^{-1}(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{lc}\pm\sqrt{x+1}+1,&x\in\lbrack-1,0\rbrack\\\pm\sqrt{1-x}-1,&x\in(0,1\rbrack\end{array}\right.}$$

But by differentiating is we can't find $(f^{-1})'(3)$. But $f^{-1}(x)$ should be defined on all $\mathbb{R}$..

So... What I am doing wrong? What is really happening here?

Also when I try to graph them:
[image]

We can see that $f^{-1}(x)$ takes values only in $[-1,1]$.

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but technically, $(f^{-1}(3))' = 0$. Indeed, $f^{-1}(3)$ is a number (not a function) and therefore its derivative, rigorously speaking, would be $0$. 
What you're looking for is $(f^{-1})'(3)$ is suppose?

Comment: It is extremely unclear what the notation $(f^{-1}(3))'$ even means. On its face it looks like it's trying to differentiate a constant. Is it supposed to mean $\frac{d}{dx}f^{-1}(x)$ at $x=3$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm yeah, the derivative of the inverse function at $x=3$.

Comment: Oh you're right my notation is wrong, wait let me edi that

Comment: Its okay now I think

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty seems to be writing down $f^{-1}(x)$.

To solve this question, we look separately at the range of $f$ , for it is on that range that $f^{-1}$ can be defined.

Let us look at $x^2 - 2x$ for $x \leq 0$. As $x$ decreases, this goes to $+ \infty$. The mimimum of this function is at $x = 0$, with the value $0$. So this piece of the function has range $[0,\infty)$.

Next, $-x^2-2x$ for $x > 0$. Clearly, as $x \to \infty$, this goes to $-\infty$. Furthermore, this is equal to $-x(x+2)$, and as $x \to 0$ this approaches zero. Hence,the range of this function is exactly $(-\infty,0)$.

So $f$ is surjective. It is also injective, as seen by you.

---

Now, given $y \in \mathbb R$, suppose $y \geq 0$. Then $y$ is in the range of the first piece, so there is $x \leq 0$ so that $x^2 - 2x = y$. Completing the square and solving, $x = 1 \pm \sqrt{y+1}$, but since $x \leq 0$ we must have $-$, not $+$ in the answer. Therefore, $x = 1 - \sqrt{y+1}$, so $f^{-1}(y) = 1 - \sqrt{y+1}$.

Similarly, if $y < 0$, then $y$ is in the range of the second piece, so there is $x \geq 0$ such that $-x^2 - 2x =  y$. Solving, $x = -1 \pm \sqrt{1-y}$, but we want $x \geq 0$ so the sign is $+$ not $-$, hence $f^{-1}(y) = -1 + \sqrt{1-y}$.

Consequently, we have :
$$
f^{-1}(y) = \begin{cases}
1 - \sqrt{y+1} \quad y \geq 0 \\
\sqrt{1-y} - 1 \quad y < 0
\end{cases}
$$

---

Since $3$ belongs to the first piece, $f^{-1}$ is differentiable at $3$, and the derivative is $\frac {-1}{2 \sqrt{y+1}} = \frac {-1}4$ at the point $3$.

Your mistake was not knowing which sign, $\pm$ to choose from the two quadratic solutions.

---

To get the meaning of the green graph, note that if $x = y^2 - 2y$ for some real number $y$ then $x +1 = y^2 - 2y + 1 \geq 0$ so $x \geq -1$. This is why the graph does not go behind $x = -1$ : you do not have real solutions beyong that point. Since you have already restricted $x \leq 0$, the green graph is confined to $-1 \leq x \leq 0$. Something similar happens with the yellow graph.

Neither of these is an inverse anyway : $x = y^2 - 2y$ is *not the graph of the inverse* of the function $y = x^2 - 2x$. This is a misconception.

---

You may graph $f^{-1}$ to see the correctness of the answer.

Comment: Thank you, but however why on desmos it is defined only on $[-1,1]$?

Comment: You have to plot the above inverse function $f^{-1}(y)$. You seem to have plotted some different functions, for which I have explained, why they are only defined on $[-1,1]$. Try to plot the piecewise function $f^{-1}(y)$ which I have described above, then you will see that it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

First, your first solution is correct.

Regarding the second approach: 
let us define an auxiliary variable $y := f(x)$. This will help avoiding confusion between different domains. 
So, let us check the two cases.

**Case 1:** $x \leq 0$. In this case, we have $y = x^2-2x$ and we want to find a formulation $f = g(x)$. Let us proceed. 
Completing the square gives us $y = (x-1)^2 -1$ or $y+1 = (x-1)^2$. It follows that $x = \pm \sqrt{y+1}+1$ and (remember) $x \leq 0$. Therefore, we **have** to use the negative square root. Thus $x = g(y) = -\sqrt{y+1}+1$, for $y \geq 0$.

As you said, $y$ is bijective, hence you can simply evaluate the derivative of $g$ at the point $y = 3$. It follows 
$$
g'(y) = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y+1}}.
$$
Therefore $g'(3) = -\frac{1}{4}$, as above.

**Case 2:** is unecessary given that the function is bijective.